# Pandas groupby losing columns if empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df2=df[["A", "B"]].groupby(["A"]).sum()
```

If df is not empty, df2 will have column B.
If df has now rows, d2 will have no rows but also no columns.
How to preserve "B" column if df has no rows?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B'])

df2 = df[["A", "B"]].groupby(["A"])[['B']].apply(str)

print(df2)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [B]
Index: []
```

Comment: also  `df2.index
Index([], dtype='object', name='A')`  will be there